How do you summarize data frame in pandas based on values
I have a data frame like this
df
Node_Name size  count
Abc1       10     2
Abc1       20     2
Zxd        30     3
Zxd        40     3
Zxd        80     3
Ddd        10     4
Ddd        40     4
Ddd        80     4
Ddd       100     4

I need subset this data frame of as this.
If the count value per Node_Name is 2 or less, take min value per Node_Name. If count is 3 or more, remove the max and add the size of values excepr for tge max value group by the Node_Name.
For example final_df should look like this:
Node_Name size  count
Abc1        10     2
Zxd         70     3
Ddd         130     4


Is the count value related to the group size if grouped by the node name?

What do you need help with exactly? What's stopping you from doing it yourself? To start, do you know how to use groupby?

original question: aggregation that depends on a group value
If I understand well the logic, for each group with groupby.apply, take the lowest 2 values and sum if count >2 else the min:
out = (df.groupby(['Node_Name', 'count'], sort=False)['size']
         .apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(2).sum() if x.name[1] > 2 else x.min())
         .reset_index()
      )

NB. x.name contains the identifier of the group (for the first one this is ('Abc1', 2)) thus x.name[1] is the count.
Output:
  Node_Name  count  size
0      Abc1      2    10
1       Zxd      3    70
2       Ddd      4    50

variant: sum all but the largest
out = (df.groupby(['Node_Name', 'count'], sort=False)['size']
         .agg(lambda x: x.sort_values().iloc[:-1].sum())
      )

# or
out = (df.groupby(['Node_Name', 'count'], sort=False)['size']
         .agg(lambda x: x.nsmallest(len(x)-1).sum())
      )

Output:
  Node_Name  count  size
0      Abc1      2    10
1       Zxd      3    70
2       Ddd      4   130


count could be greater than 3 sometimes. If it's greater than or equal to 3, sum the size of lesser 2

Not quite: it just happens here that Abc1 has only two entries, but the OP states that if count <= 2 then the minimum value is to be taken even if there are more than two entries.

@mozway, fir Abc1, out value should be 10, not 30

Oops indeed, I will fix that in a bit, got caught up by smth IRL

@NickD it's fixed, thank you for letting me know!

@mozway, sorry I had to update the question. I f the count us greatercthan 2, remove max size value add the others. If the size is 2, take the min value of size

@user1471980 if you understood the logic, that's virtually the same, see edit

@mozway, if the count 4, I need to add lesser 3 values, if five , add the lesserc4 values, basically remove the max, and add the other values group by Node_Name

OK, then I guess a groupby.agg a bit like my original approach, have a look

@mozway, quick question. This solution worked but what if count value is 1. This does not work. It gives 0 if you apply ur solution. If count is one, I need to take the size as is.

@user1471980 I think you might want to use .agg(lambda x: x.nsmallest(max(2, len(x)-1)).sum())


Sort the dataframe by node_name and values
Create a filter that grabs first and first two values by using shift with the node_name column
Create another filter for count > 2
Use filters to filter down to relevant rows and take a groupby sum

df = df.sort_values(['Node_Name', 'size']).reset_index(drop = True)

first = df['Node_Name'].shift(1) != df['Node_Name']
first_two = df['Node_Name'].shift(2) != df['Node_Name']

more_than_two = df['count'] > 2

df2 = df[first | (first_two & more_than_two)].groupby('Node_Name')['size'].sum()

Alternate method of filtering down rows using groupby groups:
from functools import reduce

rows = []

for ind in df.groupby('Node_Name').groups.values():
    if len(ind) > 2:
        rows.append(ind[0:2])
    else:
        rows.append(ind[0:1])

df.loc[reduce(lambda a, b: a.append(b), rows)].groupby('Node_Name')['size'].sum()


import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Node_Name': ['Abc1', 'Abc1', 'Zxd', 'Zxd', 'Zxd', 'Ddd', 'Ddd', 'Ddd', 'Ddd'],
    'size': [10, 20, 30, 40, 80, 10, 40, 80, 100],
    'count': [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

aa = df.assign(
    size=df.groupby('Node_Name')['size'].transform(
        lambda x: x.min() if x.count() <= 2 else x.sum() - x.max()
    )
).drop_duplicates(subset=['Node_Name'])

'''
  Node_Name  size  count
0      Abc1    10      2
2       Zxd    70      3
5       Ddd   130      4
'''

bb = df.assign(  size = df.groupby('Node_Name')['size'].transform(
lambda x : x.nsmallest(len(x)) if x.count() <= 2 else x.sum() - x.nlargest(1).sum()    
)
).drop_duplicates(subset=['Node_Name']).reset_index(drop=True)

'''
  Node_Name  size  count
0      Abc1    10      2
1       Zxd    70      3
2       Ddd   130      4
'''

